# Re-initialize or destroy Bootstrap datepicker dynamically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, methods, datepicker, destroy

Is there a way to destroy the Bootstrap datepicker dynamically updating its options like format, beforeShowDay, etc.?
I know that the jQuery UI datepicker has a destroy method but Bootstrap's has not. It only has the `.('remove')` method but its not working.

My goal is to modify the options of the datepicker when changing an input, for example:

```
$('#employee').change( function() {
   $('#date').datepicker('destroy'); //not working 'cause bootstrap hasnt a destroy method
   $('#date').hide();
});
```

Then I call the initialize function when the input changes:

```
function updateCalendar(){
     $('#date').datepicker({
          format:"dd/mm/yyyy",
          beforeShowDay: updateC  //function that modifies the available days to show
     });    
 }
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('remove');
```

Make sure you have your date picker object in DOM before removing it.
Without removing you can hide the calendar and change the format of date and update it .

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('update');
```

Comment: it was destroying the datepicker before initializing for the first time. After checking that ir worked :)
Thank you!

Comment: `remove` has been deprecated, use `destroy`

Comment: If you are using the latest version of the jquery datepicker Instead of $('.datepicker').datepicker('remove'); use $('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');

Answer (score 2):

You can Use:

`$('#element_id').datepicker('destroy');`

I called this just outside my ajax call. My ajax call was creating the datepicker dynamically. After the call was made I destroyed the object.

Like below:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'my_ business_functions.php',
     data: {func_call: 'my_method_name', my_parameter: my_parameters},
     type: 'post',
     success: function(output) {
         //all my stuffs here
        $('#element_id').val(datepicker_value);
        }
    });
    $('#element_id').datepicker('destroy');
```

This served my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found it more to just remove the element's ID, clone it, and add the ID back in.

Comment: Yes, it would have been more helpful if you have shown us in sample codes what exactly you did that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Propably you are using datepicker with input btn group, I mean you with a date icon button. So, you should not choose just input element when you want to destroy it and reinit. You should select div has "date-picker", then remove and init again.

Answer (score -2):

```
forceParse: 1
```

In your options.
It will parse the input date field value every time.